# Calculate $ \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(\delta(x))^{(2p+2m)}(0)}{m!}x^m $

Tags: taylor-expansion, normal-distribution, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am trying to calculate the sum bellow

$$
\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(\delta(x))^{(2p+2m)}(0)}{m!}x^m
$$

for $0 \leq p$ and $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.

Any idea

Thanks

Comment: What does $(\delta(x))(0)$ mean?

Comment: @NinadMunshi : that means $\delta(0)$ and  $(\delta(x))^{(2p+2m)}(0)$ the $(2p+2m)^{th}$ derivative of $\delta(x)$ at $x=0$